# How to Resolve "RemoveObjectAtIndex"

Tags: ios, nsarray

I have an property:

@property (nonatomic, retain) QBChatDialog* dialog;

When i make it nil in viewWillDisappear, it giving me error

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

      self.dialog = nil;

}
```

I am getting following error:

```
-[__NSArrayM removeObjectAtIndex:]: index 2147483647 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

even i don't use "removeObjectAtIndex". I think this is calling somewhere internally.

How to trace this.

my Complete Stack trace is:

```
   (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x05504494 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x05cd6e02 objc_exception_throw + 50
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0540b2cd -[__NSArrayM removeObjectAtIndex:] + 445
3   Qboy                                0x0026d23e -[TWMessageBarViewController statusBarHidden] + 43262
4   Qboy                                0x002acffc QBAFQueryStringPairsFromKeyAndValue + 110104
5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x05cea060 _ZN11objc_object17sidetable_releaseEb + 238
6   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x05ce9361 objc_release + 65
7   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x05ce9318 objc_storeStrong + 39
8   Qboy                                0x0007a35a -[ChatVC .cxx_destruct] + 298
9   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x05cd58e2 _ZL27object_cxxDestructFromClassP11objc_objectP10objc_class + 116
10  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x05cd5869 object_cxxDestruct + 20
11  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x05cdfcb6 objc_destructInstance + 48
12  CoreFoundation                      0x0550e57c -[NSObject(NSObject) __dealloc_zombie] + 156
13  UIKit                               0x038de904 -[UIResponder dealloc] + 162
14  UIKit                               0x03855e85 -[UIViewController dealloc] + 2296
15  Qboy                                0x0017bf93 -[QMChatViewController dealloc] + 835
16  UIKit                               0x040c1b75 -[UIViewController(UIKitManual) release] + 88
17  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x05ce934f objc_release + 47
18  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x05cea52d _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_119AutoreleasePoolPage3popEPv + 371
19  CoreFoundation                      0x053d48a8 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 24
20  CoreFoundation                      0x0540c43c __CFRunLoopRun + 2364
21  CoreFoundation                      0x0540b846 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
22  CoreFoundation                      0x0540b65b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
23  GraphicsServices                    0x06eef664 GSEventRunModal + 192
24  GraphicsServices                    0x06eef4a1 GSEventRun + 104
25  UIKit                               0x03688eb9 UIApplicationMain + 160
26  Qboy                                0x000db84a main + 138
27  libdyld.dylib                       0x062cca25 start + 1
28  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
```

Please suggest me. What to do?

Comment: Provide the code because of which it is happening.

Comment: You might have an empty array.

Comment: I update my question. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

error tells you that

you have an array which is empty/nil

and after that you are removing an item of object which object is no longer exists in this array

**Trick:** for quick fix search '**removeObjectAtIndex**' all overs the project(from upper left 3rd search button). if find one/lot observe those

Answer (score 0):

You may not be calling `removeObjectAtIndex:` inside `viewWillDisappear:`, but you are calling it within `-[TWMessageBarViewController statusBarHidden]`. Look there and I think you'll find the source of your crash!